# Applescript code completion shortcut

Tags: editor, applescript, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm new with applescript and this may seems dumb... but I have no clue at how to auto complete the code completion in the editor!?

I checked the option Use Script Assistant in the preferences.

For exemples When I create a new variable then I start to write it later in the code I can see in light grey color the word I want to auto complete.

But what is the shortcut to auto complete it? I tried spacebar, enter, shift + arrows... and so on

but have no clue

thanks for your help :P

Comment: At this point I suspect most people are at least running Sierra now. Stephane Pirou's answer should probably be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use Script Assistant's Auto-Completion with the <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Comment: Wow. Apple used the "abort" key to confirm. Sums up a lot of what I think about AppleScript.

Comment: The other editor out there besides Emacs, "vi", uses the escape key to change modes.   For many programmers, hitting escape comes naturally.

Comment: On 10.11.6 it is luckily alt+esc and not anymore only esc. With esc I had problems in the AppleScript of Spark, which will close the window (without saving) on esc :(

Answer (score 11):

It probably changed whith sierra or High-Sierra :

It's now `option` + `escape` keys.

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I don't like the Escape key to auto-complete.

To add your own key to auto-complete, go to

- System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

and add an entry for *Script Editor* (select "Other" and then go to Utilities in Finder) named `Complete`. You can then choose your own shortcut to auto-complete in the Script Editor.

---

Here's a screenshot for `Ctrl + Space`.

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Preferences... Keyboard... Shortcuts... App Shortcuts... Add... Scri... Scri.... Nope, no 'Script editor'. I'll try 'other'. Oh, there it is. Greyed out, so I can't select it. Wow, thanks, Apple. El Capitan wins again.

Comment: I can add keyboard shortcuts for Script Editor on macOS Catalina. It's not in the menu, and it's not possible to select directly with Other, but it *is* possible to drag the Script Editor application into the slideout panel after opening Other.

Answer (score 0):

The menu shows <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd> will auto-complete and it seems that just <kbd>esc</kbd> will as well ***but***, the <kbd>esc</kbd> key to me is "escape", meaning "stop current computer operation" so it feels like I am trying to *not* accept auto-complete!

Instead, using the keyboard shortcuts and adding a shortcut of <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> to accept the auto-complete feels natural during typing...

Here is a visual setup:

(in Big Sur, same action, different look in earlier macOS versions)

[image]
[image]